# Getting an error with the Location package in flutter. how to fix?

Tags: gradle, flutter, error-handling, package, location

Im trying to get the package:

```
location: ^2.3.5
```

bute when I try to run the app I keep getting this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 64 in debug mode...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\WinDows\Desktop\Flutter_Work\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

> Configure project :app
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
WARNING: API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getJavaCompile(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getMergeAssets(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
         *********************************************************
WARNING: This version of image_picker will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
         See [enter link description here][1] for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
         This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
         *********************************************************

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.0 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
root project 'android' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
  Command: C:\Users\WinDows\Desktop\Flutter_Work\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Here is my build.gradle inside the android folder:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

Here is my gradle.properties:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
```

and I import this code in my AndroidMainfest:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I added exactly what the package asks for but my app stopped running...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your dependencies,

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

just change your kotlin version to above "1.3.0" in your build.gradle file. Like,

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
```

And you're done.